# React Native application with subscription: custom Stripe flow?

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I've developed my custom onboarding with a one-time payment using Stripe which, if succeded, updates subscription data in my database. Then I have logic in my React Native app that will determine whether the user's subscription is expired.

Sadly, as I understand App Store requires Apple's In App Subscriptions to achieve such task. Does Google Play have the same requirement? Will my app be rejected?

https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap is the only crossplatform solution I've found but does anybody know how to set up a year subscription on both platforms?

Comment: have you got any solution for it.

Comment: Use a combination of react-native-billing for Android and react-native-in-app-utils for iOS

Answer (score 1):

yes, in google play, you can make a free app or a paid one. Within this app, you can insert In-app products which could be subscriptions as well. It a pickle. I give my app for free for 3 months and then charge for subscription. there is a grace period you can define as well